# Can we use triggers directive for multiple stage

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Hi I want to know whether multiple stages can have a `triggers` directive, if no then I need some way to schedule each stage

```
pipeline{
    stages{
        stage{
            triggers{cron (#some_exp)}
            steps{
                # Some steps
            }
        }
        stage{
            triggers{cron (#some_exp)}
            steps{
                # Some steps
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger each stage separately that means that each stage is probably a separate business logic unit and therefore you should seriously consider creating a separate job for each step in order to avoid packing them all into a single job with multiple triggers and packed logic.

However if you still want to achieve what you want you can do it with the [Parameterized Scheduler Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/) which enables you to define cron triggers that trigger the job with a specific environment variable, you can then use this variable as a condition to determine which step to execute.

Here is an example for implementing it:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'STAGE', defaultValue: 'setup', description: 'Which stage to run')
    }
    triggers {
        parameterizedCron('''
        */2 * * * * %STAGE=setup
        */3 * * * * %STAGE=build
        ''')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Setup') {
            when {
                expression { STAGE== 'setup' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "In Setup stage - STAGE parameter is ${STAGE}" 
                ...
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            when {
                expression { STAGE== 'build' }
            }
            steps {
                echo "In Build stage - STAGE parameter is ${STAGE}"
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```